# LIBSVM (nonlinear regression with e-svr using linear kernel)

Tags: python, regression, nan, libsvm

In what cases is libsvm supposed to returned [nan] as the predicted values of nonlinear regression (with e-svr using linear kernel)?

Is there a faq available ?

btw.

My inputs are not nan, but the std.dev of some of my feature columns are nan. Although when i remove this features nothing seems to change...

Answer (score 0):

From the faq (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html)

Q: Why the code gives NaN (not a number) results?

This rarely happens, but few users reported the problem. It seems that their computers for training libsvm have the VPN client running. The VPN software has some bugs and causes this problem. Please try to close or disconnect the VPN client.

Comment: I currently use ubuntu 14.04 and I do not have any VPN software installed... this does not make sense...

Comment: This also happens in my windows computer that also does not run any vpn software... so it does not seem to be the case

Comment: Another possibility: missing values

Comment: My data does not contain nan,inf or missing values but the std.dev of some of my feature columns are nan. Although when I remove this features nothing seems to change...